# Change timezone according with daylight saving time

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm actually running `aws-lambda` functions in a region with ***daylight saving time***, but when using `new Date()`, it doesn't returns with +1 timezone.

Is there a way to enable ***daylight saving time*** for my lambdas? How did you guys work on this in a `javascript` environment?

Comment: Note that the region where the Lambda function is running should be immaterial.  The clock in all AWS regions is set to UTC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this information was fundamental, so I solve it using `moment-timezone`, changing timezone back to region where lambda belongs. Thanks!